# building piscope on Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit

Tags: pigpio

I have used piscope on Raspberry Pi OS and recently wanted to use on Raspberry Pi OS 64bit.

I followed the instructions on http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html

```
# To utilise a pre-built executable use one of the following make commands

make hf     # to run on a Pi
```

This makes a 32 bit executable.

It appears to be feasible to build from source, but as Raspberry Pi OS 64bit seems to be the most popular I would have expected a prebuilt binary (there is a x86_64 build option).

Has anyone run piscope on 64 bit - and if so HOW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around to building from source as I am now running 64bit on my Pi4.

The `WARNING: Installing gtk+-3.0 uses a lot of SD card space.` was true (although there was only 1 *-dbg package) but there were lots on Nvidia files and other rubbish.
I actually used a spare SD Card for the build so I can revert to a normal install.

The binary piscope is 76592 bytes

Answer (score 0):

If it is a recent download the tar should contain a 64-bit build.

Try

`make x86_64`

Comment: I did try this but it didn't work (as it appears to be a x86 executable) I want to run on Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit ARM.  Options are `make hf     # to run on a Pi
make x86_64 # to run on a 64 bit Linux PC`

Comment: Sorry,  I didn't read your question properly.  You will need to build from source.